# FloatingActionButton with TextView dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamically-generated

I want to create a FloatingActionButton and textview dynamically and i want to add this in my xml root layout but there is a problem FloatingActionButton is hiding my textview??

```
RelativeLayout main_rel_layout = findViewById(R.id.main_rel_layout);
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
textView.setText("Hello ");
textView.setTextSize(100);
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = new FloatingActionButton(this);
floatingActionButton.setCustomSize(400);
relativeLayout.addView(textView);
relativeLayout.addView(floatingActionButton);
main_rel_layout.addView(relativeLayout);
```

My xml code

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_rel_layout">

<!--
    I want to add textview over floating button 
-->


    </RelativeLayout>
```

here is the problem

[image: textview is not showing]

Comment: Have you tried adding `floatingActionButton` before `textView `?

Comment: @B.M yes, I tried but i got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    RelativeLayout main_rel_layout = findViewById(R.id.main_rel_layout);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    textView.setText("Hello ");
    textView.setTextSize(100);
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    final FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = new FloatingActionButton(this);
    floatingActionButton.setCustomSize(400);
    frameLayout.addView(floatingActionButton);

    relativeLayout.addView(frameLayout);
    relativeLayout.addView(textView);
    main_rel_layout.addView(relativeLayout);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to set above text view

```
textView.bringToFront()
```